# AngularDart Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

I'm using AngularDart and I can't figure out how to inject my entry point dependencies.

Main.dart:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_dart/app_component.dart';
import 'package:angular_dart/app_component.template.dart' as ng;

@GenerateInjector(const [
  const Provider(MyRepository, useClass: ng.MyRepositoryImpl),
])
final InjectorFactory appInjector = ng.appInjector$Injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: appInjector);
}
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  providers: [ClassProvider(MyRepository)]
)
class AppComponent {
  MyRepository myRepository; //This is not getting injected
}

abstract class MyRepository {
}

class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {
}
```

My question is about the runApp method and the ng.AppComponentNgFactory. I am not seeing how the injection is resolved.

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT:** What I’m looking for is how to tell the compiler to generate a line like:

```
new AppComponent(new MyRepositoryImpl);
```

And consume it like

```
class AppComponent{
final MyRepository _repo;

AppComponent(MyRepository repo) {
this._repo = repo;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[ClassProvider(MyRepository)]` in your `app_component` tell the compiler to override what you have set in your `main.dart` file.

Try this:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
)
@Injectable()
class AppComponent {
  final MyRepository _myRepository;

  AppComponent(this._myRepository);
}
```

EDIT:

Your main.dart file is incorrect, you have to reference the injector from the main.template.dart :

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_dart/app_component.dart';
import 'package:angular_dart/app_component.template.dart' as ng;
import 'main.template.dart' as self;

@GenerateInjector([
  ClassProvider(MyRepository, useClass: ng.MyRepositoryImpl),
])
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But still ng.appInjector$Injector is undefined. Do you know what’s going on?

Comment: Worked like a charm!
After your answer I just needed to add @Injectable() to my App Component.

Thanks!